# Pergunta Fechada: Busca Binária em Lista Encadeada

Tags: debate, fechamento, razões-fechamento, perguntas-fechadas

A seguinte pergunta foi fechada como ampla demais: [Busca binária em lista encadeada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100441/busca-bin%C3%A1ria-em-lista-encadeada)

Na minha opinião, a pergunta não está ampla demais. O escopo dela é muito bem definido: Busca Binária em Lista Encadeada. Inclusive o autor cita que não é possível saber previamente a quantidade de elementos da lista, o que fecha um pouco mais o escopo da pergunta.

Gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês, pois pode ser que eu esteja vendo diferente, já que eu criei uma resposta para a mesma. De qualquer maneira, creio que a resposta que apresentei também tem escopo muito bem definido e não vejo como poderiam haver respostas tão diferentes para uma questão como essa.

Comment: Alguns dos que fecharam frequentam o [chat], rola de perguntar diretamente

Comment: Obrigado @brasofilo.

Comment: A pergunta é ampla demais porque não tem parâmetros suficientes. Basicamente pediu um tutorial de como fazer uma em termos gerais. Não é um problema específico. Faltou o código de onde está aplicando aquilo que é falado na pergunta. Aí respontas podem acertar ou não o que ele precisa. Vira loteria. Eu quase fechei por não ser claro, mas achei que faltava detalhes mesmo. E estava certo, dava pra responder na base da loteria.

Comment: Acho que o AP se focou mais na *possibilidade* de uma solução existir, não em pedir uma solução pronta. A resposta do Cantoni responde ao problema apresentado - "Como buscar numa lista encadeada simples" - sem entrar em detalhes de implementação (como a estrutura dos nós, quantos e quais ponteiros usar, etc, etc). A resposta é concisa e completa, o que não deveria ser possível numa pergunta "ampla demais". Também não concordo com a sinalização.

Comment: Obrigado @Gabe. Foi essa análise que fiz. Realmente não vi como ter tantas respostas distintas para essa pergunta.

Comment: a tag debate ainda existe?