# O que é uma pergunta ampla?

Tags: debate, fechamento

## Introdução

Eu vejo muitas perguntas sendo fechadas como amplas e que talvez não sejam tão amplas assim. Isto fica mais claro quando a pergunta tem a chance de receber uma resposta antes do fechamento. Há casos que a resposta salva a pergunta.

Eu já falei antes e não vou insistir nisto, até porque sei que não vai mudar nada. Embora a filosofia da SE seja de salvar o máximo de perguntas possível, o mecanismo e a cultura do site não incentiva muito isto.

Não queremos respostas ruins, que não tenham sentido, que não ajudem de verdade quem pergunta ou outras pessoas. Deveria haver mais facilidades de impedir essas respostas que só poluem o site. Como não existe, o que é feito é fechar perguntas que podem conter este tipo de resposta. Tentamos adivinhar o que pode acontecer. Muitas vezes acertamentos, embora a maioria nunca saberemos.

Claro que há casos que a pergunta não tem chance de produzir algo útil. Especialmente me casos de perguntas fora de escopo e muitas vezes as que não estão claras (estas podem estar para alguém, então é preciso cuidado).

## Confusão do que é amplo e baseado em opinião

As que causam mais confusão são as baseadas em opiniões e amplas.

Pra falar a verdade hoje eu vejo que o motivo anterior do mecanismo "não construtivo" era melhor. O problema não é as respostas serem baseadas em opiniões, é elas serem só baseadas nisto. Quase ninguém entende o que é isto. Na verdade o problema é a resposta não construir nada útil. Mas acho que nem há um problema grande com estas perguntas aqui. Há algum. Vejo algumas perguntas que não precisariam estar fechadas.

Se tivesse um mecanismo melhor para evitar as respostas que sejam só opiniões sem sentido, aí talvez o motivo de fechamento da pergunta nem precisasse existir. Talvez só existiram perguntas não claras o suficiente para sobreviverem.

No caso das amplas, o maior motivo é não ter critérios suficientes para responder. Ou seja, a resposta ficaria longa demais ou produziria várias respostas, cada uma falando de uma parte e nenhuma sozinha estaria certa ou todos estariam, de alguma forma certas.

A pergunta ter que escrever um tutorial completo sobre o assunto também é motivo de fechamento.

O fato da resposta ter que ser longa não é motivo para fechar por ser ampla. Há casos que a resposta pode ser focada e ainda assim ter que ser longa. O problema é o foco, não o tamanho.

Parece que algumas pessoas não entendem isto.

Se alguém pode dar uma resposta legal, focada sobre o assunto, mesmo que a resposta tenha que ser longa, porque não pode estar no site?

Claro que, dentro dos critérios atuais e como o mecanismo funciona de fato, a pergunta tem que ajudar, não pode incentivar respostas bobas. Tem que ter algum aviso que a pessoa não está querendo um tutorial, não quer criar uma lista de coisas e ver qual a popularidade dessas coisas, não quer que fale de um monte de coisa ao mesmo tempo.

Pedir para listar coisas de uma forma geral, que tem um relação, tem um fio único que rege esta lista, que a lista tenha que ser "completa" e não colocar itens para formar a lista, ter um foco do que está falando, ter pelo menos implicitamente que os detalhes não são importantes, tudo isto é importante.

Se não estiver assim, será que podemos editar para melhorar antes de fechar?

Se a pergunta é útil de verdade, é objetiva, vai acrescentar alguma coisa que vai ajudar os programadores sem que sejam levados a erro por ser superficial demais, não merece uma chance?

Não podemos ter uma pergunta que lista certos pontos e que se alguém quiser detalhes, vai perguntando individualmente?

#### Exemplos

Por exemplo, tem gente que acha que esta pergunta é ruim: [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/101) O que seria melhor ter dezenas de perguntas isoladas perguntando item por item? Fazer de conta que estas coisas não devem ser debatidas? Não é melhor ter um local único para centralizar isso. E se detalhes precisam ser dados em cada item, que sejam, sob demanda.

Então tem porque realmente fechar a pergunta [Quais as diferenças mais relevantes entre C# e Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/101)? Ou é preciosismo? Alguém consegue dar um motivo real que vá além do "é a regra", "eu acho que é ampla", "é longa demais"?

Se acha, como algo deste tipo poderia ser perguntado de forma a ser aceito no site? Não tem como? Este tipo de conteúdo causa mal para o site?

Lembrando que esta pergunta está ótima para várias pessoas aproveitarem. Se especificar demais será ótima só para o AP. Qual tipo de pergunta preferimos aqui no site? A que ajuda um monte de gente ou a que ajuda só uma pessoa?

Eu peguei este exemplo ocorrido agora para exemplificar o problema. Sintam-se a vontade para mostrar outros exemplos de perguntas fechadas indevidamente por motivos semelhantes.

Se a pergunta tivesse sido fechada antes de eu postar um esboço, ela ficaria sem resposta alguma, ninguém teria a resposta que parece ter sido bem aceita pela comunidade, que parece ter ajudado o AP e muita gente ter uma noção melhor sobre o assunto e agora ter a oportunidade de fazer perguntas mais específicas.

Estou enganado que a resposta prova que ela podia receber um boa resposta?

Ela está específica. Se fosse um site de automóveis, podemos falar de carros, não precisamos só falar de parafusos. Só porque carros tem milhares de componentes, é assunto proibido? É claro que se a pergunta quiser que descreva cada aspecto do carro, fica inviável mesmo. É claro que a se pergunta pede para explicar todo o funcionamento do carro, não dá. Uma pergunta que queira saber quais são as partes de um carro não pode ser feita tranquilamente?

Eu já li os argumentos das pessoas sobre o fechamento até agora. Nenhum me convenceu. Todos repetem a regra, mas não mostram onde isto é ruim para o site. Todos ignoram a resposta, mesmo quando dizem reconhecê-la.

Outros exemplos (abre uma resposta e coloque os seus que sejam claramente injustos porque as pessoas não entendem estes motivos de fechamento, por exemplo, [Como programar GUI em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80324/101) eu acho que poderia estar aberta, mas não digo que seja claramente injusto que esteja fechada):

- [Porque a Linguagem D é pouco usada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105117/101)
- [Banco de Dados embarcado com C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96689/101)
- [Quais são os valores recomendados para database MySQL (id, usuario, senha e email)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16967/101)
- [É viável utilizar MySQL com Entity Framework 6 e obter boa performance de CRUD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58226/101)
- [Quais seriam casos reais de uso de programação funcional no mundo .NET (F#)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/613/101)
- [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101)
- [Quais são os pros e contras de utilizar jquery no desenvolvimento mobile?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76622/101)
- [Como fazer uma função onde toda vez que que uma variável seja chamada esteja acrescida de mais 1?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30236/101)
- [Carrinho de compra armazenar no cliente ou server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11218/101)

## Conclusão

Note que não estou dizendo que todo tipo de pergunta assim deva ficar aberta, tem que analisar cada caso. Tem que analisar o texto, a intenção, tem que ver se não pode melhorar. Não queremos discussões, não queremos escrever tutoriais, mas queremos publicar informações relevantes.

Tem vários outros fechamentos que vejo que ocorrem meio no automático, sem a pessoa refletir de fato sobre o que é. Acontece, eu entendo. Já fiz isto também. Mas precisamos evitá-lo. Aqui está um oportunidade para refletir.

Enquanto a SE não nos dá um mecanismo melhor de filtrar conteúdo ruim, podemos tentar salvar as perguntas que podem produzir algo útil?

A regra não pode ser aplicada porque é a regra. Ela deve ser aplicada para atingir um objetivo. Ela deve filtrar conteúdo ruim, que não agrega nada útil.

Tem um monte de pergunta que é bem pior, inclusive coisas que eu respondi que mereciam muito mais ser fechadas do que casos como este.

Gostaria de ver respostas que mostrem com clareza porque isto deve ser fechado. Mudo de opinião se tiver bom motivo.

**Pode votar para reabrir  algumas das perguntas citadas?**

Comment: Queria ter mais facilidades para fazer busca: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4793/101, queria achar todas fechadas pelo motivo ampla, que eu respondi (afinal se eu respondi, eu acho que mereciam resposta) pra ver quantas estão na mesma situação, mas o sistema não ajuda. Alguém sabe fazer isso no SEDE?

Comment: Depois postarei outros tipos de fechamentos que acredito ser indevido. Não tem porque fechar tanta coisa que não é tão problemática assim.

Comment: @bigown [Isso que procura?](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/revision/428470/545862/minhas-perguntas-fechadas-como-ampla-demais)

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu consigo criar 100 respostas completamente diferentes para a maioria das perguntas feitas aqui. Mais ainda em outros sites da rede, especialmente no ptLang :). Então vamos sair fechando tudo. Há uma assimetria de critério. Há uma falha na perspectiva. Tem que olhar para o todo e não só para isto. Eu concordo que é possível que cada um diga uma diferença, mas a pergunta não pede isto. Se a pessoa responder assim o erro é da resposta, não da pergunta. A pergunta foi fechada sem ter culpa de nada. E se ela tem, me fala qual é, que eu vou lá e arrumo.

Comment: @bigown não tem nada a ver com isso, quando eu puder eu faço uma resposta explicando como deve ser.

Comment: @Randrade alguma coisa por aí, mas nem tanto, pode ser um começo pra chegar onde quero. Pena que não conheço a modelagem do DB da SE. Não é curioso que não tenha nenhum de 2014? Não parece que o pessoal ficou mais radical? Ainda que algumas aí merecem o fechamento mesmo. E acho que não está listando um monte de coisa, preciso verificar melhor. Tem algumas +/- recentes que eu lembro que foram fechadas e não estão aí.

Comment: @bigown Eu não tenho tanto tempo assim aqui, mas realmente eu percebi uma mudança. Agora, se você ordenar a busca por score (answer.Score DESC) você verá que tem algumas perguntas nesse mesmo sentido. Com respostas boas mas fechadas.

Comment: Essa, por exemplo, é uma pergunta ampla. Ampla de 'muito comprida', haha, :D

Comment: @Earendul é que eu não gosto de discussões rasas :P A superficialidade é que faz os fechamentos serem feitos sem critério.

Comment: Olha só, em 2016 que nem completamos um mês, tem mais ou menos o mesmo número de fechamentos de 2014 inteiro. 2015 tem bastante. Dá pra pensar, não? https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/428475/minhas-perguntas-fechadas-como-ampla-demais?UserId=101

Comment: Votei para reabrir. Concordo quando diz:  "O problema é o foco, não o tamanho"

Comment: @bigown o povo anda louco com os fechamentos...

Comment: Provocando: acho que você concordaria que [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110319/) é ampla. Porém, vejo chance de ela servir como mote para uma boa resposta. Isso salvaria uma pergunta dessas?

Comment: @bfavaretto é uma boa discussão. Eu acho que está muito ampla mesmo, não dá parâmetro nenhum, nenhum foco, é só uma lista enorme de coisas que não tem fim, a maioria das coisas que você vai escolher para colocar serão baseados em opiniões (note que não estou nem dizendo que a resposta seria, mas o critério do que colocar na resposta ou não, seria arbitrário. Ou seja, é uma lista tendendo para o infinito, sem sentido :D É possível ter uma boa resposta? Até é. Se tiver, eu acho que salva. Você lembra que deixamos salvar várias assim no passado, mas se tiver uma ruim antes, enterra de vez :D

Comment: @bfavaretto Na minha opinião o problema principal da pergunta pode estar em perceber a que tipo de "preocupações" o AP se refere. Isso poderá originar respostas diferentes em função de abordagem escolhida para formular a resposta.

Comment: @ramaral isso mesmo, cada um pode achar o que bem entender do que está sendo perguntado. Isto é a definição de ampla. E o que diferencia de ser pura e simplesmente "não clara". Dá para entender o que está sendo perguntado, mas cada um do seu jeito. O "não claro" e "amplo demais" (note o demais, que é importante) são muito próximos em muitos casos. Tem vários casos que eu erro e escolho um quando deveria ser o outro. Isto eu acho compreensível.

Comment: Exemplo de resposta boa em pergunta ampla demais: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64731/101 Não há uma delimitação do que precisa ser escrito aí, cada um pode dar o tutorial que bem entender, escolher quais as partes são relevantes para o aprendizado da pessoa. Não há um critério objetivo para escolher o que responder. Este é um caso que dá para dar 100 respostas diferentes, todas boas, e uma não passar perto da outra. Não tem um fio que faça ter uma resposta mais ou menos uniforme. E eu não sei como consertar este tipo de pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta que poderia ser reaberta se melhorasse um pouco: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32324/101 a resposta não é muito boa (mas também não é ruim) porque a pergunta não é boa. Pergunta difícil de analisar, eu não sei o que faria, preferi não fazer nada, ou seja, deixar decidirem por mim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15197/101. Exemplo de resposta que eu acho que enterrou a pergunta, mas muita gente achou que não: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28208/101 Algo aberto, ruim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82140/101  Faça tudo pra mim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28591/101

Comment: Você notou que a resposta do Jon Skeet que você "linkou" na sua resposta está numa pergunta fechada no SOen? Que só está ainda disponível por questões históricas e não é um exemplo de pergunta a ser feita no site? Acho que entender o motivo disso explica o mesmo comportamento no SOpt.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Ela não está fechada, está bloqueada. Você entende que aqui as regras são diferentes? Entende que a razão histórica é que depois passou a ter o Programmers.SE onde este tipo de pergunta deveria ser postada? E que aqui não temos esta separação?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109951/101 Curiosamente ninguém achou esta ampla, talvez porque não estava clara que era ampla. E está se mostrando bem ampla. Ela pede algo geral e detalhes de cada caso. Isto realmente fica difícil responder em um lugar só. Mas ninguém enxergou assim. Eu percebo que tem certos gatilhos para as pessoas escolherem o que fechar. Certas palavras usadas, certos padrões. A análise deveria ser um pouco mais profunda.

Comment: @bigown Embora ache que essa pergunta não seria bem recebida nem no Programers.SE porque neste caso ela teria sido movida para lá, eu entendo tudo isso que você disse. A questão é: será que quem votou para fechar entende isso? Eu não votei para fechar...

Comment: @EMBarbosa este é o motivo deste debate aqui. Me parece que algumas pessoas não estão entendendo isto. E o problema é que as demais não se envolvem. Você não sabe se é porque concordam com o fechamento ou não, mas o fato é que só 3 pessoas votaram para reabrir. Eu, o ramaral que reconheceu que a pergunta pode ser pertinente e mais um que desconheço quem seja. O resto, que pode votar, não quis fazer nada, inclusive moderadores. As pessoas só gostam de fechar, elas não gostam de reabrir, por isso fechar precisa de cuidado.

Comment: Concordo bigown, não pude entrar tão ativamente no debate por conta do serviço aqui (isso me impediu), mas tenho um ponto de vista parecido com o que foi exposto por você. Quem contrariou, até que teve alguns argumentos que julgo válidos, mas insuficientes para justificarem suas opiniões. Meu parecer final, é de que a maioria perguntas são fechadas por causa de opiniões pessoais, do que em atender a um objetivo do site.

Comment: @bigown, Eu gostaria uma formulação melhor sobre essa frase sua: "Enquanto a SE não nos dá um mecanismo melhor de filtrar conteúdo ruim," - O que seria um mecanismo melhor de filtrar o conteúdo ruim que a SE poderia prover?

Comment: @EMBarbosa aqui não tem espaço para isto, e nem sei se quero insistir nisso, já falei várias vezes em outras perguntas. E mesmo que eu centralize tudo em um local, acho que seria perda de tempo, a SE não vai mudar, é só ficar recitando poesia.

Answer (score 12):

Vou focar na pergunta de C# versus Java. Antes da sua edição, a pergunta mostrava mais a intenção do AP ao fazê-la: escolher uma das duas linguagens para estudar/trabalhar. Acredito que você tenha removido essa parte pois ela incentivaria respostas opinativas.

Isso me fez pensar sobre a utilidade das respostas. Uma utilidade clara é ajudar as pessoas a decidirem qual linguagem aprender antes (digo "antes" porque é sempre bom aprender várias linguagens). Não sei bem se tem outras e quais seriam, especialmente para quem for capaz de responder a uma pergunta como essa com tantos detalhes como você fez. Acho que é um tipo de conteúdo mais útil para quem não tem experiência com uma das linguagens, ou com nenhuma.

Nisso acho que a primeira parte da sua resposta, antes do "item por item" é excelente. Já o "item por item" me leva a querer classificar a pergunta como ampla. Eu não consigo achar essa segunda parte tão útil porque ela é muito detalhista (e imagino que tenha potencial para ser mais detalhista ainda). Cada ponto daqueles renderia uma pergunta no site, e dificilmente alguém vai precisar das respostas todas ao mesmo tempo.

Mas, veja só, agora eu estou julgando a pergunta pela resposta. Nesse tipo de pergunta, talvez não tenha outro jeito. O fato de você ter postado uma boa resposta não impede que apareçam outras 10 ruins. Ou outras 10 boas. A gente não tem como saber. Pensando assim, acho que essas perguntas merecem um pouco mais de tempo antes de poderem receber votos de fechamento. Eu já costumo esperar na maioria desses casos, já que como moderador posso fechar as perguntas sozinho. Nisso a fila de fechamento atrapalha, porque uma vez na fila a pergunta acaba fechada mais rapidamente.

Comment: Talvez seja muito detalhista, e acho que se for para ser mais que isto, aí é ampla mesmo. Mas talvez não seja tão detalhista, só é longa mesmo :) Eu acho esta parte a melhor, a mais objetiva, a que ajuda mais saber o que é diferente. De fato se alguém quiser os detalhes tem que fazer perguntas individuais. Só porque ela pode ser mais detalhada, não significa que deva ser. Eu acho que está faltando perspectiva para todos que estão respondendo. Eu concordo com o que está sendo dito sobre isto, mas não entendo porque não pode ter uma resposta geral e superficial.

Comment: Concordo bastante com a conclusão. Em todos os pontos dela.

Comment: @bigown ninguém contesta que a sua resposta é muito boa e que pode ajudar alguém. O que eu, pessoalmente, contesto é que normalmente esse tipo de perguntas faz com que hajam muitas respostas de má qualidade. Mas é simples, é testar para ver.

Comment: Essa segunda parte é boa para quem já conhece razoavelmente bem pelo menos uma das linguagens. E essas pessoas provavelmente vão ter dúvidas sobre um ou outro aspecto específico, não sobre tudo. Já para os novatos, acho que confunde. Não vai ser a presença ou não de classes estáticas, por exemplo, que vai ser determinante na escolha da pessoa. Provavelmente ela nem sabe o que é isso ainda :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu já usei esse argumento, e não deixa de ser verdade que essas perguntas atraem muito conteúdo ruim. O problema é por causa disso **nós** deliberadamente impedirmos o surgimento de conteúdos bons.

Comment: @bfavaretto isso é muito subjetivo. Eu também posso fazer um tutorial de Java e colocá-lo aqui como resposta a uma pergunta assim, não deixa de ser bom conteúdo, mas queremos isso aqui?

Comment: @bigown Quando você pede uma resposta geral e superficial, seria ao que está perguntado no título? Porque no final da pergunta você diz querer justificativas para o fechamento, e não uma definição de "ampla demais". É difícil definir, porque cada pergunta tem suas particularidades, como você mesmo falou.

Comment: @JorgeB. tem um que contesta a resposta sim :D Você chegou no ponto. Já foi testado, tem outras perguntas assim abertas e não causou problema. O problema são as perguntas que são fáceis demais, que são "caça-níqueis", aquelas que serão feitas e respondidas sem a pessoa se dar ao trabalho. É claro que a pergunta precisa ser bem feita. É sutil o que é bom e o que não é. O tutorial não é bom mesmo, ele não tem foco. Embora eu esteja falando em algo abstrato. Vai que alguém faça de um jeito bom. Acho difícil, mas só consigo analisar o caso concreto pra cravar.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sinceramente, não sei se queremos isso aqui. Só podemos julgar se aparecer. Se dermos a chance das respostas aparecerem, depois a gente pode negativar o que for ruim.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu não acho que a resposta vá fazer a pessoa decidir, mas ali ela vê "tudo" o que precisa analisar nas linguagens. Tem um começo para fazer outras perguntas. Eu tenho feito muito isto nas minhas respostas, principalmente me perguntas que não são uma maravilha. Respondo alguma coisa e deixo a porta aberta para a pessoa pedir mais detalhes em outras perguntas. Se ela faz ou não já é outro problema. Alguma informação **útil** é melhor que nada. O título em um pouco "catchy" :) Mas é coerente com o todo. Eu acho que a decisão tem que ser concreta, mas quero o debate geral.

Comment: Falando especificamente, ninguém vai fazer 2000 perguntas para descobrir 1950 é essencialmente igual nas duas linguagens e em 50 tem diferenças. Esta é uma forma de informar o básico para pessoa poder ir adiante. Eu acho que perguntas assim até precisam ser mais bem feitas ainda. Ninguém chegou neste ponto até agora. Estou aguardando. As perguntas precisam deixar claro que não querem qualquer respostinha. Por falha do mecanismo.Acho q este tipo de pergunta deveria ser no mínimo protegidas.Já ajudaria, mas pouco.O mecanismo precisaria ser melhor.Obviamente evito proteger onde tem resposta minha

Comment: Com o perdão do trocadilho, tem uma discussão mais ampla :) Dentro do modelo atual não sei se deveria existir os fechamentos de "ampla demais" e "baseado em opiniões". Se vamos responsabilizar a pergunta, o problema é que ela não está clara. Como vamos saber se as respostas serão amplas ou baseadas em opiniões? Tá, dá para ter uma ideia, mas podemos errar fácil. Já que não tem uma forma boa de responsabilizar a reposta ruim, e a cultura na rede é esta, só podemos afirmar o que temos certeza. Sabemos que a pergunta não está clara o suficiente para não deixar respostas ruins serem postadas.

Comment: A minha opinião está dada e vou agir como sempre agi, o que achar que deve estar fechado ponho para fechar e depois a comunidade é que decide.

Comment: @bfavaretto já viste a pergunta no SOen?

Answer (score 8):

Que atire o primeiro voto quem nunca votou numa pergunta fechada ou quem nunca respondeu uma pergunta que estava pra ser fechada (ou que iria ser fechada). Pior do que isso, que atire o primeiro voto que nunca respondeu uma pergunta que nitidamente estava com problemas? O próprio @bigown fez *mea culpa* nesses itens e isso foi nobre da parte dele.

Eu fui um dos que classificou a referida pergunta como ampla demais. Nem por isso, deixei de votar na resposta (após a reorganização do autor). Fiz isso, pois a resposta estava boa e isso é completamente independente da pergunta. O meu voto foi por dois motivos: pelo conteúdo e pelo esforço que o autor teve de escrever tudo aquilo.

Todo fechamento de uma pergunta tem uma carga de subjetividade. A questão é que o fechamento é julgado por pessoas que pensam diferente, dependendo da pergunta, muito diferente. Portanto, discordar faz parte e muitas vezes faz bem.

Eu, por exemplo, não concordei e continuo não concordando com o fechamento dessa pergunta: [Pergunta Fechada: Busca Binária em Lista Encadeada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4605/14674). Não sei se podemos comparar ambas, mas essa última foi fechada como ampla demais e tem um escopo muito mais delimitado. Os votos da minha resposta foram na maioria concedidos após o fechamento.

Eu permaneço com a minha opinião que a referida pergunta está ampla demais e aqui vão os meus argumentos:

> Título da pergunta: Quais as diferenças mais relevantes entre C# e
>   Java?

São muitas diferenças (vide reposta)! Um exemplo com escopo mais bem definido: Qual a diferença entre Java e C# no tratamento dos Generics?

O autor cita:

> Pois bem, minha pergunta tem como objetivo obter uma resposta que
>   possa mostrar qual a linguagem mais adequada com o que quero
>   trabalhar. Pretendo trabalhar principalmente na área Web.

A mais adequada para se trabalhar? Isso é bem subjetivo, pois depende de vários aspectos que também são subjetivos. Depende de empregabilidade, depende de gosto, de experiência. Obviamente, as duas são adequadas em vários contextos. Enfim, eu não consigo responder essa parte sem que haja um contexto e mesmo que tivesse, provavelmente não estaria nas regras do site pra responder.

O autor cita:

> Queria saber quais as diferenças mais relevantes que eu deva saber que
>   existem entre essas duas linguagens. Porque estou perguntando isso
>   aqui? Porque normalmente no meu dia-a-dia quando faço essa pergunta,
>   meus colegas sempre demonstram um "favoritismo" em relação a uma
>   dessas linguagens, apesar de não ter sido essa minha pergunta a eles
>   rsrs.

O autor cita o "favoritismo" (que realmente existe) e pede algo imparcial. Entretanto, a própria resposta cita no início e logo antes de detalhar os itens técnico que:

> De fato quem trabalha só com uma vai ser tendencioso para ela.
>
> Já adianto que na maior parte dos casos a escolha será feita por gosto
>   ou por algum aspecto político e não técnico.

Isso já mostra como é complicado responder uma pergunta dessa.

O autor cita:

> Minha intenção nessa pergunta é ver as diferenças para que as vendo eu
>   possa decidir em qual dessas linguagens quero investir meu tempo.

Se este é realmente o objetivo do autor, então fica uma carga muito grande para quem vai tentar responder. Como montar uma resposta tão imparcial no SOpt que leve o autor que está com dúvida a tomar a sua própria decisão. Amplo demais, na minha opinião. Até mesmo fora do escopo, pois o SO não existe pra isso.

Por isso eu citei nos comentários (que foram apagados) que o melhor é montar perguntas específicas sobre os temas técnicos que o autor tem dúvida.

Pra finalizar, espero que o autor não leve isso para o lado errado. A pergunta está bem escrita, passa a mensagem, só não concordo que ela se encaixe no site pelos motivos acima citados. Como dica, fica: Aprenda as duas linguagens. Como o @bigown disse, ambas estão embasadas no mesmo paradigma e você pode, efetivamente, aprender as duas e aprender bem.

Comment: Um ponto importante é a resposta ser diferente da pergunta. Qual é o problema da pergunta? A resposta não mostra que ela podia ser bem respondida? Os mais novos não acompanharam várias discussões de respostas que salvavam perguntas ruins, ainda que eu nem ache que esta pergunta seria ruim. Ter uma carga de subjetividade não significa que sempre esteja certo fechar. Ultimamente a subjetividade parece ter pendido para fechar em primeiro lugar, depois avaliar se está certo ou não. Isto não ocorria no passado.Curiosamente quando eu liderava mais a comunidade :P E tem quem ache que eu sou fechador.

Comment: A resposta ser longa não é motivo para ser ampla. Um problema apontado já foi resolvido, basta usar a edição. A citação da tendenciosidade é justamente para ser imparcial. Falar que é gosto é justamente para colocar perspectiva, algo que está falando na avaliação se a pergunta é ampla ou não. A resposta em si mostra pontos objetivos. Mesmo que isso seja um motivo, então a pergunta deveria ser fechada como baseada em opiniões e não como ampla. É claro que a decisão será do autor. Ele só precisa de informações objetivas para ajudar a decisão. Ninguém vai dizer pra ele qual é a melhor.

Comment: A pergunta deixa claro que não é isto que ele quer. Seria uma loucura montar uma pergunta para cada item, só para citá-los. E ainda não resolveria totalmente o problema. Ou seja, está sugerindo dar uma volta ao mundo pra ir ali na esquina. Parece coisa governamental. A regra pela regra. Ainda não me convenceu. Claro que respeito a opinião de cada um, mas não vi um motivo para fechar a não ser algo do tipo "eu li em algum lugar que a regra é fechar isso".

Comment: cantoni. de modo algum levei a mal o fato de quererem fechar a pergunta. De modo algum, vejo nisso um problema. Isso em algumas situações se torna necessário para um bom repositório de perguntas no so que de fato estejam de acordo com a proposta do mesmo. Porém ainda assim, mesmo com sua resposta, acredito que se trata de um equívoco. A única parte da sua resposta que aceito como argumento válido é quando vc faz uso da minha citação "Pois bem, minha pergunta tem ...." e dá seu parecer. Eu poderia excluir ou reformular a pergunta, mas ainda não fui convencido de que a mesma não cabe aqui no so

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva, obrigado por compreender de maneira positiva. Quando fiz meu julgamento foi por tudo que estava escrito. No comentário que foi apagado eu disse que li várias vezes sua pergunta até tomar a atitude de votar pra fechar. Teve uma análise, não foi um tiro no escuro.

Comment: Seu comentário foi apagado? Você mesmo apagou? Não entendi

Comment: Não. As vezes os admins dão uma limpada nos comentários pra deixar a coisa menos poluída. O problema, nesse caso específico, é que fez a discussão perder um pouco do conteúdo.

Answer (score 5):

bigown eu dar +1 numa resposta não quer dizer que eu ache que a pergunta ou a resposta mereçam estar no site. Você poderia muito bem fazer um excelente tutorial de Java e colocá-lo como resposta que eu provavelmente dava +1 pelo esforço e pela qualidade de conteúdo. Só que acho que esse não é o intuito do site.

Primeiro, acho que esse tipo de pergunta acaba por gerar muitas respostas de opinião, não é o caso da tua, mas tens noção que é uma excepção?

Segundo, acho que este tipo de perguntas acaba por gerar respostas demasiado amplas, ou seja, nada objetivas, cada um fala do que sabe de cada linguagem e compara o que sabe comparar. Podemos assim acabar por ter 1000 respostas TOTALMENTE diferentes de um assunto que, supostamente deveria gerar respostas no mínimo parecidas, ou as diferenças não são as mesmas para toda a gente? É que se não forem, então voltamos ao caso da opinião.

Concluindo é verdade que a tua resposta salvou a pergunta, a meu ver salvou de ser excluída e negativada, mas acho que NUNCA de estar fechada.

Comment: Sem dúvida o voto na resposta nada tem a ver com a pergunta ser boa ou não para o site. Se pode gerar opinião, então o fechamento deveria ser este. Cai no que eu falei, a SE não nos dá um bom mecanismo para filtrar as respostas boas das ruins. Tem um, mas ele não é bom. Devemos punir a pergunta porque alguma resposta pode ser ruim? Isto é o padrão que se usa na rede mesmo. Mas devemos fazer isto? Devemos impedir uma boia resposta de surgir porque uma ruim pode aparecer? Eu acho que há casos e casos. A pergunta deixa claro que deve ser respondida por quem conhece ambas.

Comment: Eu acho pouco provável que surjam muitas respostas muito diferentes do que eu respondi. Claro que podem surgir algumas ruins, algumas tendenciosas, mas é um problema da resposta. Eu concordo que minha resposta ajuda salvar a pergunta. Mas salvou, não? Pra mim ficar fechada é bom, não tenho concorrentes :D Mas esta não é a questão. Se eu não tivesse criado um esboço na hora que foi postado eu nunca teria a chance de postar a resposta. Eu tive que usar um truque para o site ter um conteúdo que, pode não ser uma maravilha mas, está sendo considerado interessante.

Comment: @bigown respondendo a sua pergunta *Devemos impedir uma boia resposta de surgir porque uma ruim pode aparecer?* eu sinceramente acho que sim, é por esse mesmo motivo que o SO tem o sucesso que tem por ter qualidade. Se há um tipo de questões de X vs. Y que costumam atrair respostas de má qualidade e afetar a qualidade de conteúdo do site, eu acho que devemos mantelas afastadas do site.

Comment: Ah e mais uma coisa @bigown, esqueci-me de dizer que esse é o tipo de pergunta que tem de ser atualizada com frequência, ou senão corre o risco de ficar ultrapassada em pouco tempo. Mas nem sei se isto é um grande problema, mas fica aqui também registado.

Comment: O SO tá cheio de coisas ruins, tudo aberto. Tem um monte de coisa boa fechada. Eu acho que dá para se basear no que eles fazem, mas não podemos cometer os mesmos erros deles. Lá por ter gente demais, os critérios são loucos. Aqui não precisa ser. A pergunta não está afastada do site :) Fechar não afasta ela. Eu concordo com a ideia que você tem, não com a execução dela. De fato ter que ser atualizada é um problema real. Eu sei que eu farei, outros não. Embora muitas corram o risco também. Mas essas atualizações devem ocorrer em uma forma mais controlada. Não é como mudar preço e coisas do tipo

Comment: @bigown eu nem sequer estou a comparar com o SO, estou só a dizer que acho que esse tipo de perguntas traz muito mais coisas más que boas ao site. Se elas começarem a parar de ser fechadas vais ver que vai começar a haver muito lixo por ai... Muito mais lixo alias.

Comment: Entendo, só discordo, que estes raros casos vão causar problema. É diferente das perguntas que são feitas só por fazer, que as pessoas vão responder só pra participar. Estas causam problema.

Comment: @bigown eu estou-me a lembrar de umas quantas perguntas de diferenças entre linguagens e ferramentas... "Quais as principais diferenças entre Zend e Laravel?" etc, etc, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Para obtermos uma resposta mais objetiva em uma pergunta ampla(como a pergunta feita), devemos usar a abstração.

1- [Abstração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o) : Abstração (do latim abstractio) é uma operação intelectual que consiste em isolar, por exemplo num conceito, um elemento à exclusão de outros, do qual então se faz abstração.

Na terminologia filosófica, a abstração é o processo de pensamento em que as ideias são distanciadas dos objetos. A abstração usa a estratégia de simplificação, em que detalhes concretos são deixados ambíguos, vagos ou indefinidos.

2- [Pergunta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pergunta) : É uma frase cujo objetivo é convidar um ouvinte ou leitor a dar uma explicação, uma informação, ou, em qualquer caso, uma interrogação que demanda, ou solicita uma resposta.

Na filosofia a pergunta é o que gera toda a discussão ao que cerca o todo.

3- Amplo( adjetivo) :

```
  1. que tem grandes dimensões; vasto, espaçoso.
  2. muito extenso; abundante, copioso.
  3. que é rico, farto.
  4. que apresenta considerável largura; folgado.
  5. de grande alcance; abrangente.
  6. que tem significado abrangente.
  7. que é aberto, franco, generoso.
  8. que não tem limites; sem restrições.
  9. que possui grande envergadura; vasto, desenvolvido.
```

Fazendo uma alegoria (talvez até pertinente) ao nosso ambiente computacional, levemos em conta o processo desde a entrada de dados ou a realização de uma pergunta.

Para se obter a resposta a uma pergunta será realizado (a grosso modo) 2 processos , tanto por nós, como pelas máquinas.

1- [Análise sintática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) :  É o processo de analisar uma sequência de entrada (lida de um arquivo de computador ou do teclado, ou falada por exemplo) para determinar sua estrutura gramatical segundo uma determinada gramática formal.

2- [Análise semântica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sem%C3%A2ntica) :  Trata a entrada sintática e transforma-a numa representação mais simples. Esta camada da interpretação ou compilação( a grosso modo) fica igualmente encarregada de analisar a utilização dos identificadores e de ligar cada uma delas a sua declaração. Nesta fase é também esperado que no processo da compilação verifique que cada expressão definida tenha um tipo adequado conforme as regras próprias da linguagem.

**Após está reflexão, podemos observar alguns detalhes :**

*Uma pergunta ampla feita em um ambiente adequado, pode gerar conhecimentos relevantes.*

***O StackOverflow-PT não é um ambiente adequado para perguntas amplas e sim perguntas elaboradas de forma que induzem inevitavelmente a uma resposta o objetiva.***

*O StackOverflow-PT-Meta como na própria [definição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) é a parte do site onde os usuários discutem o funcionamento e as políticas do Stack Overflow em Português em vez de discutir o programação em si. Ele é separado das perguntas e respostas principais para reduzir a confusão e oferecer um espaço legítimo para que as pessoas perguntem como e por que este site funciona do jeito que funciona.*

***A pergunta feita neste tópico é de suma relevância, ela revela a necessidade de buscarmos sermos objetivos (no SOPT), pois para respondê-la por completo seria necessário abranger uma gama numerosa de conceitos, como por exemplo a [pragmática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragm%C3%A1tica), que por sua vez envole mais uma série de outros conceitos.***[image: Conceitos que englobam conceitos]