# Porque uma pergunta clara e objetiva que pode ser respondido em 2 ou 3 linhas foi fechada como ampla?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Veja a pergunta [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101).

Eu gosto de ar respostas completas e até redundantes já que isso é técnica didática para quem não conhece o assunto. Talvez por isso algumas respostas minhas não tão precisas sejam preferidas à respostas tão objetivas que fica difícil para quem não sabe nada daquilo. Não estou dizendo que aplico a técnica da melhor forma, eu sei que falho nisso, mas conheço a técnica e faço o que posso.

Eu poderia ter respondido assim:

> A primeira linguagem de programação foi o código binário. Os programas eram entrados por chaves mecânicas representando os bits e pulsos elétricos indicavam isso, não havia conceito de arquivos. A montagem do programa era feita todo manualmente fora do computador, apesar de tedioso era a única solução.

Dava pra ser até mais sucinto, mas teria menos informação relevante.

Não quero reabrir monocraticamente, até por ter participado. Embora deixar fechada só ajuda a minha não ter mais concorrentes. Minha intenção é fazer o que julgo ser o certo.

Anteriormente já [questionei sobre o fechamento de outras perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4801/101), algumas mais questionáveis. Mas essa não tenho dúvidas.

Não coloco em dúvida a boa fé de quem votou. Acredito que pelo menos alguns tenham bons motivos para acreditar nisso. Mas também acredito que alguns não entendam bem o que é realmente o "muito ampla". Outros talvez acharam a pergunta longa demais e falando de coisas desnecessárias, ou até mesmo a existência do fato do AP dizer que o tema é abrangente tenha disparado um gatilho em alguns.

O tema é abrangente, mas a pergunta não é tanto assim. Este é o tipo de pergunta que ajuda muita gente e se encaixa no modelo de Q&A.

Eu editei para tirar o que não era relevante. Mas ela perguntas exatamente a mesma coisa.

Se ainda não entendem o que é algo amplo, está aí uma oportunidade de reflexão e debate. Se realmente não perceberam que a pergunta é bem contida, é oportunidade para reverter a situação.

Vocês concordam comigo? Há outros problemas? Posso reabri-la?

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Até gosto de respostas longas, quanto mais detalhado melhor. **+1** para reabrir.

Comment: Não concordo. Responde o que o AP da pergunta quer especificamente saber. Depois, a partir de outro parágrafo separado da resposta suscinta pode encher liguiça.

Comment: Eu entendo que as respostas é que deram um escopo "respondível" para a pergunta. Teria muito mais para ser falado do assunto mesmo se não repetisse praticamente nada do que está nas respostas atuais. Como já foi respondida, não vejo problema na reabertura. Quando acontece de respostas boas serem dadas, já se evita naturalmente que a postagem vire um "poço de devaneios". Se não tivesse respostas, eu realmente esperaria o autor ser mais objetivo nos pontos tratados, para depois reabrir.

Comment: @Bacco obrigado pelo retorno. Entendo o que quer dizer, o risco dessas respostas voluntariosas nesses caos sempre existe mesmo.

Comment: Acredito que deveria melhorar a política de fechamento das perguntas porque em alguns casos o colega pede para quem fez a pergunta ajustar a mesma, e mesmo assim ele já vota no fechamento da mesma, isso atrapalha porque eu já fiquei impedido de fazer novas perguntas por causa de uma pergunta que foi fechada mesmo eu fazendo os ajustes solicitados.

Comment: @itasouza toda vez que uma pergunta é editada, nós recebemos aviso e oportunidade para votar ou não na reabertura. É importante o fechamento o mais rápido possível no caso de problemas, para evitar respostas que fiquem inválidas após a edição. Se sua pergunta foi editada e não foi reaberta, pode ser que a comunidade tenha entendido que a edição não foi suficiente e votado para manter fechada. Lembrando que basta 5 pessoas votarem para reabrir, e normalmente são bem mais que 5 pessoas que votam.

Comment: @bigown antes da sua edição a pergunta não estava muito clara para mim, eu não consegui compreender qual era a real necessidade do AP, porque o titulo dizia uma coisa e a pergunta expressava varias outras coisas, eu fui um dos primeiros a votar, e votei como não clara o suficiente (talvez tenha sido falha minha em compreender, eu não sei). Eu gostei da pergunta e deixei meu +1 acho muito importante saber um pouco da historia (na minha opinião qualquer profissional da área de TI deveria saber), mas o AP poderia ter dado uma refinada nela.

Comment: @bigown mas eu confesso, que no momento de votar eu fiquem em dúvida entre votar como ampla demais mas votei como ñ clara msm Parecia que o AP queria compreender todo o processo da evolução dos computadores, existe muitos anos de estradas e muitos livros que contam a historia da computação em detalhes. Esta foi uma das minhas interpretações da pergunta.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho a claridade dela até acho possível. Eu nem acho que não estava clara, mas estava cheio de coisa sem necessidade. Note que só tirei coisas. Entendo que o titulo era diferente, ma vejo mais como um complemento, afinal não são coisas antagônicas. Mas é perfeitamente justificável essa interpretação. A pergunta não estava e nem está ainda na melhor forma. Obrigado pelo retorno. Faltam duas pessoas que votaram se manifestar. E outras que votaram para deixar fechada quando tinha voto para reabrir. Tem 3 votos para reabrir.

Comment: @bigown sua edição melhorou bastante a pergunta, votarei para reabri-la.

Comment: Reabri com o quinto voto.

Comment: Eu só vi agora, mas concordo contigo. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pergunta possuía alguns detalhes que *acho* que influenciaram para o fechamento da pergunta.

#### Antes das Edições

Se olhar a versão original, que foi realmente fechada, o próprio autor da pergunta fala que o tema é **MUITO** abrangente. Isso poderia levar ao entendimento de ampla.

> Eu sei que é um tema MUITO abrangente e pode fugir um pouco do escopo de SO, mas eu não tenho mais a quem recorrer.

Outra parte que chama a atenção é quando ele fala sobre entender como as coisas evoluíram. Se for falar de tudo até chegar nas linguagens atuais, pode englobar como amplo também.

> [...]Eu queria esclarecer todas essas dúvidas e entender como as coisas foram evoluindo.

Temos também a questão do envolvimento de vários assuntos (claro, estão interligados) na pergunta, como:

- Computadores Mecânicos
- Cartões Perfurados
- Relés
- Válvulas
- 0 e 1
- Assemby

Se formos ver bem, tudo está interligado, mas que leu pode **não ter** entendido bem, e achado que a pergunta queria informações sobre todos esses itens distintos.

#### Após as Edições

Após [esta edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/156521/3), várias partes conflitantes foram removidas, inclusive as dúvidas do AP se a pergunta pertencia ou não ao site.

Podemos ver que a parte principal não sofreu muitas alterações, mas deixar o texto mais limpo ajuda a entender o problema.

#### Sua resposta sucinta

Como você disse na pergunta, poderia ter respondido a pergunta com esse texto:

> A primeira linguagem de programação foi o código binário. Os programas eram entrados por chaves mecânicas representando os bits e pulsos elétricos indicavam isso, não havia conceito de arquivos. A montagem do programa era feita todo manualmente fora do computador, apesar de tedioso era a única solução.

Porém, não acho que esse texto responda a pergunta. Ele pede mais entendimento sobre algumas coisas, e podemos ver uma certa dificuldade em entender como era feito as alterações de softwares e a questão da **"compilação"** de códigos em 0 e 1.

Mas, entendi o seu texto. Se lermos a pergunta, temos a impressão de que se trata de **qual foi a primeira linguagem**, mas ao lermos mais, ele pede mais informações. Por isso acho que somente esse texto responderia a pergunta.

#### Conclusão

Em minha humilde opinião, eu acho que a pergunta deveria ser reaberta por dois fatores, as **respostas** e o **tema**.

As respostas são excelentes. Respondem o que foi perguntado e ainda muito mais sobre o assunto. E não podemos esquecer do tema, que é algo muito importante e que poucas pessoas realmente conhecem.

E para finalizar, não acho que deva ser reaberta apenas, mas também ser protegida ou quem sabe se tornar uma wiki. Falo isso porque as respostas são mais como um artigo do que uma resposta, e com isso seria um ótimo material de estudos para novos e velhos profissionais da área.

Comment: Só não entendi a parte de tornar wiki.

Comment: @Math As respostas falam bem sobre a evolução dos computadores. Isso eu acho um assunto que pode ser melhorado eventualmente. Com isso, se fosse transformado em [wiki](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2248/20615) poderia dar mais "liberdade" para isso. Porém, disse que "talvez, quem sabe...". Isso pois ~aquilo~ não são respostas, e sim artigos.